# Find common elements from two lists (with PhoneNumber) in android

Tags: android, arraylist, comparison

I have created a android demo application.In this I get data into tow array list.one is all contact list of device.and second is all element list stored in parse database.i have successfully get the element of both...

now I manually save the same contact number in my phone contact which is saved in my parse database.

My question is that how to get and display the same contact number from both list into Third one list.

any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `String` Lists, use `retainAll`

```
list1.retainAll(list2);
```

Take the two lists you have created and apply the above operation, substitute `list1` with your `firstlist` name and `list2` with your `secondlist` name. It will keep all elements in your first list that are present in the second list.

See here for know how on `retainAll` - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)